CMSIS-RTOS osThreadResume will unblock osThreadFlagsWait regardless of condition
Suppose I have a thread here
void StartSensorTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartSensorTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    osThreadFlagsWait(0x01, osFlagsWaitAny, osWaitForever);
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartSensorTask */
}

It is supposed to be waiting indefinitely until 0x01 is set. Everything works fine until I called
osThreadResume(lowPwrNotiTaskHandle);

The osThreadFlagsWait will return:
osFlagsErrorTimeout

And the Thread starts running before I could set any flags.
In the CMSIS manual says that osThreadResume can resume a blocked or suspended thread, but will it also unblock a Flag Wait function with an indefinite timeout?
